# How to set Spring camel case property with uppercase environment variable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have some code to load a value as such in my Spring application:

```
@Component
public class MyElasticRestService {
    @Value("${elasticApi.baseURL}")
    private String elasticApiBaseUrl;
```

According to [the Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding), I should be able to use a relaxed binding that comes from an uppercase environment variable such as `ELASTIC_API_BASE_URL` or `ELASTICAPI_BASEURL`. But I'm confused which is correct. Both don't seem to work so I am wondering how to debug what is actually picked up.

I've loaded Spring Boot Actuator to view the `configprops` endpoint. But it doesn't have anything on the `elasticApi` prefix.

What should the correct environment variable be and how can I see how it gets translated and picked up by the application?

Comment: I suspect the uppercase URL in the @Value may be confusing it.  Try ${elasticApi.baseUrl} in combination with ELASTIC_API_BASE_URL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `@Value` annotation doesn't support relaxed bindings. Therefore you could use a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` or you use a `RelaxedPropertyResolver` to get the value from the environment.

Comment: I couldn't believe this when I read your answer.  You're right, though.  The docs actually state it only works with @ConfigurationProperties beans, if you read carefully:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding

Comment: Thanks. I'm not a Java programmer. But this answer (and the comment for the specific part in the docs) is helpful and makes sense now. I guess I'll next look at how to convert to `@ConfigurationProperties` style so I can more easily use properties as environment variables in my wrapper.

Comment: Apparently, relaxed binding is now also possible for `@Value`. You might have to use kebab-case inside the `@Value` though.

Answer (score 5):

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value, it is now very possible simply with `@Value` **as long as you use kebab-case** (all lower case with dash) for the name e.g. @Value("config.refresh-rate")

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to make it an UPPER_SNAKE_CASE, you can put it in your `application.yaml` file, this way:

```
elasticApi.baseURL: ${ELASTIC_API_BASE_URL:defaultvalue}
```

or this way doesn't really matter:

```
elasticApi:
   baseURL: ${ELASTIC_API_BASE_URL:defaultvalue}
```